# How to perform Linq select new with datetime in SQL 2008

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

In our C# code I recently changed a line from inside a linq-to-sql `select new` query as follows:

```
OrderDate = (p.OrderDate.HasValue ? 
    p.OrderDate.Value.Year.ToString() + "-" + 
    p.OrderDate.Value.Month.ToString() + "-" + 
    p.OrderDate.Value.Day.ToString() : "")
```

To:

```
OrderDate = (p.OrderDate.HasValue ? 
    p.OrderDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") : "")
```

The change makes the line smaller and cleaner. It also works fine with our SQL 2008 database in our development environment. However, when the code deployed to our production environment which uses SQL 2005 I received an exception stating: `Nullable Type must have a value`. For further analysis I copied `(p.OrderDate.HasValue ? p.OrderDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") : "")` into a string (outside of a Linq statement) and had no problems at all, so it only causes an in issue inside my Linq. Is this problem just something to do with SQL 2005 using different date formats than from SQL 2008?

Here's more of the Linq:

```
var FilteredOrders = [linq-to-sql query].AsEnumerable().ToList<Order>();

                dt = FilteredOrders.Where(x => x != null).Select(p =>
                new
                {
                    Order = p.OrderId,
                    link = "/order/" + p.OrderId.ToString(),
                    StudentId = (p.PersonId.HasValue ? p.PersonId.Value : 0),
                    FirstName = p.IdentifierAccount.Person.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.IdentifierAccount.Person.LastName,
                    DeliverBy = p.DeliverBy,
                    OrderDate = p.OrderDate.HasValue ? 
                        p.OrderDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") : 
                        ""
                }).ToDataTable();
```

This is selecting from a List of Order objects.
The FilteredOrders list is from another linq-to-sql query and I call .AsEnumerable on it before giving it to this particular select new query.

Doing this in regular code works fine:

```
if (o.OrderDate.HasValue)
    tempString += " " + o.OrderDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Here is the stack trace from the error. This is part of a large system at a school for retrieving orders for transcripts from the DB to show on screen.

```
Line 46:   
Line 47:            dt = FilteredOrders.Where(x => x != null).Select(p =>  
Line 48:            new  
Line 49:                     { 
Line 50:                         Order = p.OrderId,


Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.]    System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +51    System.Nullable`1.get_Value() +1373881 Aqueduct.Platform.Web.packages.finance_carttranscriptorder_default.<PopulateSearchResultsGrid>b__1(CartTranscriptOrder p) in D:\Repositories\aqueduct\Aqueduct.Platform.Web\trunk\packages\finance\carttranscriptorder\default.aspx.cs:48 System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
+107    System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +434    System.Linq.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
+108    Aqueduct.Core.Data.ObjectShredder`1.Shred(IEnumerable`1 source, DataTable table, Nullable`1 options) in D:\Repositories\aqueduct\Aqueduct.Core\trunk\Data\LinqExtensions.cs:116 Aqueduct.Core.Data.LinqExtensions.ToDataTable(IEnumerable`1 source) in D:\Repositories\aqueduct\Aqueduct.Core\trunk\Data\LinqExtensions.cs:49 Aqueduct.Platform.Web.packages.finance_carttranscriptorder_default.PopulateSearchResultsGrid(List`1 FilteredOrders) in D:\Repositories\aqueduct\Aqueduct.Platform.Web\trunk\packages\finance\carttranscriptorder\default.aspx.cs:47 Aqueduct.Platform.Web.packages.finance_carttranscriptorder_default.RunFilter() in D:\Repositories\aqueduct\Aqueduct.Platform.Web\trunk\packages\finance\carttranscriptorder\default.aspx.cs:101 Aqueduct.Platform.Web.packages.finance_carttranscriptorder_default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Repositories\aqueduct\Aqueduct.Platform.Web\trunk\packages\finance\carttranscriptorder\default.aspx.cs:22 System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
+14    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
+50    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: Can we see the whole query?  I'm not completely convinced that the error is actually a result of this specific change.

Comment: Have you compared the metadata between the dev database environment and the prod environment?  Any chance that the table metadata are subtly different?

Comment: The only line that has changed is this line and we never had the error previously. If I comment out this line, it works fine (minus the data the line gives me). Haven't compared the metadata between the DB's, but the dev DB is restored nightly from the Production DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's trying to convert the code into SQL. If this is just the projection side of things, I suggest you do a simple projection to the bits of data you need within the LINQ-to-SQL bit, then use `AsEnumerable` to force the rest of the query to execute in .NET itself. At that point you can do things like this with a lot more freedom. So in this case you'd have something like:

```
var query = from ...
            where ...
            select new { p.OrderData, p.SomeOtherFields };

var transformed = query.AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(p => new {
   OrderDate = (p.OrderDate.HasValue ? p.OrderDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") 
                                     : ""),
   ... });
```

Comment: I add .AsEnumerable to it now, but still no success.  I'll update my main post in a minute to show more of the select query, if that helps.

Comment: @kd7iwp: You haven't shown where you tried to add AsEnumerable.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I added AsEnumerable to the example.

Comment: @kd71wp: Okay, so what exactly is going wrong now? Assuming there's an exception, please post the full stack trace so we can see where it's failing.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I added the stack trace, I don't think it looks helpful, but hopefully you know more than I do.

Comment: @kd7iwp: Okay, so the stack trace shows that it really is *after* the LINQ query has completed. That's odd. If you get rid of the OrderDate bit, does it work?

Comment: My apologies, the mistake was a simple incorrect variable name. There's another line in the query that is the same as this one, but with a date variable of a different name. A co-worker modified that line and checked .HasValue on one variable but performed a .ToString() on a different variable. Changing to the proper variable worked. Thanks for all the help, sorry it ended up being so simple.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you please explain why I can't format the date in the first query but can be done in the second

Comment: @AliIssa: In the first case, the LINQ provider is trying to convert the query into SQL. In the second, it's executing locally, which obviously gives you a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this in Linq to SQL

```
OrderDate = (p.OrderDate.HasValue ? 
    p.OrderDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") : "")
```

It actually evaluates both sides of the case but only returns to you the "true" case. So just do something like this and it will avoid the nullable, but still give you the correct result.

```
OrderDate = (p.OrderDate.HasValue ? 
    p.OrderDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") : "")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, just to confirm, `FilteredResults` is something like this:

```
FilteredResults = [query].AsEnumerable()
```

Correct?

If so, then the only option that I can see is if `OrderID` is null. Is it a nullable type? All of your other (conceivably) nullable properties all appear to have a `HasValue` check around them or are not used at all (like `DeliverBy`), so I can't see any other options.

The only thing that I could suggest would be to remove all of the anonymous type's properties and add them back one-by-one until you encounter the error.

As an aside, there's no need to go after the `Date` property of `OrderDate.Value`, since the `ToString()` function of `DateTime` is perfectly fine formatting dates without a time component.

Comment: OrderId is not a nullable type and it is the primary key on the table and I can verify that OrderId is not null. I have also commented out lines one by one and have discovered that the OrderDate is the only line that causes the exception. You are correct about how I got FilteredResults.